# Why can't I define a `delete` method?

Tags: class, methods, d

I'm attempting to make a library with methods in a class that represent HTTP methods, such as `GET`, `POST`, and `DELETE`. I'm trying to do this with an abstract class that defines methods for each of these HTTP methods.

The problem comes in when I define a simple `delete` method for this class. This is what said method looks like:

```cpp
/**
 * A generic responder to a DELETE request.
 */
Response delete(Request request)
{
    return new Response("Method not supported");
}
```

This should work fine in theory, but on compilation I get the error, `no identifier for declarator Response`.

Why is this error occurring? Removing the `delete` method makes the program compile, but having that one method in there makes it not compile at all.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What language is it?

Comment: @xenteros language is in the tags: it's D

Comment: `delete` is already a keyword. It'd be like trying to define a method called `if`.

Comment: @user2357112, that would make sense, though is there a way to get around this easily? I'd much rather use the `delete` method name, as it corresponds directly to what I am trying to convey, and it would keep my API coherent.

Comment: `delete` is a reserved keyword in D. There's currently no way to get around it directly. Depending on your implementation you could use UDA's to mark a function as the delete function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common practice to postfix keywords with underlines to be able to use them as variable names. See https://dlang.org/dstyle.html - Keywords

Comment: My only problem with that would be that people would have to override say `delete_`, which looks odd in comparison to the other HTTP methods. Though, seeing as how `delete` is reserved, I'll have to go that way.

Thank you for the help! Accepted.